# Meaning of the term - in the blind

Tags: communication, gravity-movie

Various characters in the movie *Gravity* use the term 'in the blind' at the end of a transmission.

This is said most often by Lieutenant Matt Kowalski after the initial incident.  It is also heard amongst the garbled transmissions received by Dr. Ryan Stone in the final scenes (so is presumably said by someone on the ground).

Does it simply mean "said with no confirmed communications connection", or is there some other meaning to it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[According](http://www.foxnews.com/science/2013/10/06/gravity-science-vs-fiction/) to former astronaut [Leroy Chiao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leroy_Chiao) the term "in the blind" indicates that you're transmitting in the expectation that the receiver can hear you but letting them know that you can't hear them.

> "After the orbital debris cascade knocks out communication satellites,
>   Stone and Kowalski lose contact with ground control. They keep
>   transmitting, though, in hopes that someone is listening. Each message
>   begins with the rather haunting phrase, "Transmitting in the blind..."
>
> "Yeah, that's real phraseology and that's used in aircraft operations
>   also," Chiao says. **"You call 'in the blind' if you're not receiving
>   them, but you think they might be receiving you. You're basically
>   letting them know that you're not able to hear them."**

We can also see the phrase used by NASA mission control officers in the [final mission transcript](http://datamanos2.com/columbia/transcript.html) of the ill-fated Columbia mission;

> **HOPPE:** *Flight, INCO, commanded string one in the blind.*
>
> **CAIN:** *INCO?*
>
> **HOPPE:** *I commanded string one in the blind, Flight.*
>
> **CAIN:** *Copy.*